# Difference Between "In Time" and "Before Time"

Tags: word-usage

My boss gave me a task with completion date suppose 31 March, 2017and I completed on 28 February, 2017. Is it in time or before time.

Comment: How will my Boss rate my work. Will he say i have completed before time or he will say in time. There are both the options for him to answer

Answer (score 1):

"I completed the task in time" could mean I completed the task before a time limit or a deadline.

However, "I completed the task before time" could be confusing and not idiomatic. If someone hears it, he could ask, "what time?"

The more idiomatic expression is "[ahead of schedule](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ahead+of+schedule)" which means:

> Fig. having done something **before the time given on a schedule or
>   before the expected time**. (*Typically: be ~; finish ~.) '*I want to be
>   able to finish the job ahead of schedule*.'

The expected time or the time given is Mar 31, 2017 and when you finishd the task before the deadline expired, you can say, "I finished the task ahead of schedule."

Comment: These five options were there to reply to above query. which is the best option to reply to my query.
Achieved before time
Achieved in time
Achieved after target date
Not achieved
Will be achieved in time
Will not be achieved in time

Answer (score 1):

In almost 20 years of business experience, I never encountered the use of **before time** in this context. One better alternative is **in advance**.

In your example, the task is **finished in advance**. If you deliver the results on the same day, then you **deliver in advance**, but if you deliver the results at the agreed date, then you **deliver on time**.

The additional point I want to underline is that **finish work** and **deliver** mean different things.

Alternatives to **in advance**: **before the deadline**, **early**.

Regarding **before time**, I think it is better suited to poems and legends.

**More:** **in time** and **on time** are both correct.

- **in time** means "before the deadline"
- **on time** means (almost) exactly according to deadline

Answer (score 0):

Rathony's answer is correct if you desire correct grammer/usage.

I have listed below the answers you are apparently limited to, along with their specific meanings:

--Achieved before time: task was completed ahead of schedule/deadline.

--Achieved in time: task was completed by required deadline.

--Will be achieved in time: deadline is in the future; task will be completed on or before deadline.

--Achieved after target date: deadline is in the past and task was completed but missed deadline.

--Will not be achieved in time: task either will not be completed or else it will be late.

--Not achieved: task was not (and possibly never will be) completed.

Answer (score 0):

"I completed the task in time" would be correct. "I completed the task **on** time," sounds a little better, but that is likely just me.

"I completed the task before time," would mean you completed the task in the earliest days of world.